# FusionCharts MVC - JSON Result Not binding the data

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, fusioncharts

Am trying to create a simple bar chart (column2d) in fusionchart latest javascript version. In this exercise, I am able to get the JSON strigify output from my c# code but when I bind the return value to the fusionchart data it is not working.
my AJAX Call,

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Reports/GetTicketAnalysisChartData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
                    "type": "column2d",
                    "renderAt": "chartContainer",
                    "width": "500",
                    "height": "300",
                    "dataFormat": "json",
                    "dataSource": {
                        "chart": {
                            "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
                            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
                            "xAxisName": "Month",
                            "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
                            "theme": "fint"
                        },
                        "data": data.d
                    }

                });
                revenueChart.render();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                //alert(xhr.responseText);
                $("#chartContainer").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

If I take the json output i.e "data.d" string and place it in "data" parameter like below then it is working.

```
"data" : [{"label":"abc","value":"15"},{"label":"xyz","value":"10"},{"label":"asdf","value":"12"},{"label":"ghi","value":"11"}]
```

It is not working when I pass as object "data": data.d. 
Please help.

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the "data.d" directly to the "data" without formatting as a string and the chart is rendered correctly using your method.

Ref.- http://jsfiddle.net/sanjuktamukherjee/45u56055/[`SampleLink`](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjuktamukherjee/45u56055/)

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time on this.
You just need to convert the string you returned to a JSON object.

```
    var chartData = eval("(" + data.d + ')');
```

and then pass chartData to the fusion chart's "data" parameter

```
    "data": chartData
```